# Reported Speech: preference for using that after say/tell

Tags: american-english, british-english, indirect-speech

A student of mine has stated (based on her experience watching films and TV shows) that, when using Reported Speech, Americans will more often use 'he said that X' or 'he told us that X' whereas British people prefer to use 'he said X' or 'he told us X'.

I admit I have never noticed such a thing, nor have I heard of such a preference. Is my student on to something?

Comment: Based on my experience, it certainly seems to be the case. I've noticed a possibly related trend as an avid follower of UK sports publications, that even the most banal interview headlines usually get phrased as: "Manager reveals X" or "Player admits he likes grapes."

Comment: @Rome_Leader that may just be due to headlines needing to be terse though - do their American equivalents (ie sports papers/magazines) tend to say "that" in similar headlines?  If not, then it's not evidence...

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm saying that the preference is for words like "reveal" or "admit" that would normally be reserved for things actually unknown; American headlines don't show the same trend. e.g. "Player reveals he wants to win a championship" - big surprise, right? I'll try to dig up some direct examples (same story, different headline wording)

Comment: @BillJ Where I teach, teachers are required to teach points of divergence between British and American English (e.g. I had got / I had gotten or the different meanings of gas and chips). I usually also try to mention preferences which was what lead the student to mention her point and then ask for validation.

Comment: With respect to *say*, I think in AE, there is a difference between the included and omitted *that*, particularly with respect to vague or short answers. "Where's Frank?". "He said he had things to do", or, "he said that he had things to do". In the first one, the vagueness would be attributed to the one reporting, whereas in the second one, the vagueness would be attributed to Frank. You can use *that* to distance yourself from the statement you are reporting.

Comment: _That_ can be put before any tensed complement clause, but is never obligatory, (except at the beginning of sentences -- _That she left early is unfortunate_). However, anything that's optional tends to develop individual usage patterns which sometimes aggregate into shared social or geographical habits. But there is no general American/British difference in preference for this. Good writers vary their practice to make discussion sound natural; in speech sometimes you want to and sometimes you don't, and really that's all you can say, barring a sociolinguistic survey, which isn't on offer.

Comment: It is also obligatory if the content clause is preposed so as to precede the subject as in _That I need help I can't deny_. It's not always admissible; for example, it's inadmissible in a clause that is complement to a preposition like "before" as in *_I left before that he arrived_; in fact only a handful of preps such as "notwithstanding", "in order", and "provided" allow it. And in general, the omission of that is seen as less formal.

Comment: To my American ears, _that_ implies that you're paraphrasing, while omitting it suggests that you're quoting.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know about television, but at least in Google Books it is the British who are little more likely to use *that* to introduce reported speech. Or, more precisely, were in the second half of the 1900s. The difference is slight though. It would take an avid reader with a superhuman ability to estimate relative frequencies to spot the difference.

Mucking around a bit with Paint I managed to put a few Google Ngrams together for easy comparison:

[image]
Source: [British Englis Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(said%20that%20he%2Bsaid%20that%20she)%2F(said%20he%2Bsaid%20she)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28said%20that%20he%20%2B%20said%20that%20she%29%20/%20%28said%20he%20%2B%20said%20she%29%3B%2Cc0) and [American English Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(said%20that%20he%2Bsaid%20that%20she)%2F(said%20he%2Bsaid%20she)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28said%20that%20he%20%2B%20said%20that%20she%29%20/%20%28said%20he%20%2B%20said%20she%29%3B%2Cc0)

This pick up a lot of different stuff, like “he said he would”, “John said she was”, etc. But it also picks up “‘Yes,’ said she”. So I looked up these longer strings, that are less likely to turn up false positives, and the result are qualitatively the same:

[image]
Source: [British English Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(she%20said%20that%20she)%2F(she%20said%20she)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28she%20said%20that%20she%29%20/%20%28she%20said%20she%29%3B%2Cc0) and [American English Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(she%20said%20that%20she)%2F(she%20said%20she)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28she%20said%20that%20she%29%20/%20%28she%20said%20she%29%3B%2Cc0)

With “told me” *that* is used a lot more, but the again the British are a little keener on it than Americans:

[image] 
Source: [British English Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(told%20me%20that%20he%2Btold%20me%20that%20she)%2F(told%20me%20he%2Btold%20me%20she)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28told%20me%20that%20he%20%2B%20told%20me%20that%20she%29%20/%20%28told%20me%20he%20%2B%20told%20me%20she%29%3B%2Cc0) and [American English Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(told%20me%20that%20he%2Btold%20me%20that%20she)%2F(told%20me%20he%2Btold%20me%20she)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28told%20me%20that%20he%20%2B%20told%20me%20that%20she%29%20/%20%28told%20me%20he%20%2B%20told%20me%20she%29%3B%2Cc0)

And just on more longer, single string to make sure there is nor funny composition effect biassing results:

[image]
Source: [British English Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(he%20told%20me%20that%20he)%2F(he%20told%20me%20he)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28he%20told%20me%20that%20he%29%20/%20%28he%20told%20me%20he%29%3B%2Cc0) and [American English Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(he%20told%20me%20that%20he)%2F(he%20told%20me%20he)&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28he%20told%20me%20that%20he%29%20/%20%28he%20told%20me%20he%29%3B%2Cc0)